# How do I order an array by a value stored within a sub-array?

Tags: php

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
array(
  (int) 0 => array(
    'SomeItem' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'number' => '3',
        'created' => '2012-07-20 23:34:00',
        'modified' => '2012-07-20 23:34:00'
      )
  )
  (int) 1 => array(
    'SomeItem' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'number' => '6',
        'created' => '2012-07-20 23:34:00',
        'modified' => '2012-07-20 23:34:00'
    )
  )
)
```

How would I sort it by "number" so I could put it in ascending order of number, while still maintaining the structure?

Thank you!

Comment: `usort` is the function for that case http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php also there is many same questions asked here earlier.

Comment: http://unfra.me/2012/07/php-usort/

Comment: Next to usort there is multisort. But psst. You need to understand both (and I won't tell you both functions are documented)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Closure:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b)
        {
            if ($a['SomeItem']['number'] == $b['SomeItem']['number'])
                return 0;

            return ($a['SomeItem']['number'] < $b['SomeItem']['number']) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    );
```

Without

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['SomeItem']['number'] == $b['SomeItem']['number'])
        return 0;

    return ($a['SomeItem']['number'] < $b['SomeItem']['number']) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($array, 'cmp');
```

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate the extra work you put into giving me a solid example, that helps!